# How do I lock the title/header in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to lock the title/header of a UITableView. In other words, I want to fix it to a point and the cells should move but the title should not. The default is that when you "pull" it down, the whole table goes down along with the title. I want just the cells to go down and the tile to stay put.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a UIView and place a UITableView on it with room above for your view you would like to stay fixed.  Then manually implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource in your view controller, rather than inheriting from UITableViewController.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a UITableView that has a style of UITableViewStylePlain and implement your custom header view as a section header using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

&

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

then you will get the behavior you want.

Comment: So the key is the `UITableViewStylePlain`! I confirm that it works, but is there a way to make it work with the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` as well?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one title that you need, easiest way would be to add your custom UIView to the `tableHeaderView`

For instance:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
[label setText:@"Header table title"];
[headerView addSubview:label]
[label release]
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
[headerView release];
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: That doesn't address the desire for the header to stay fixed at the top while scrolling occurs.

Comment: I stand corrected on this one @Greg. Your approach is probably the best way to go - use a UIViewController with a custom UIView at the top and a tableView underneath it. +1

Comment: OK. Thanks for the replies. I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything in the documentation that makes this feature super easy!